# How to create single Done and Cancel button for all the PickerViews?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, swift5

I'm trying to achieve is that Done button should save the particular picker view row value to that specific UITextField.
I've two pickerview inside a single view controller.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     textField1.inputView = pickerview1
     textField2.inputView = pickerview2
     let toolBar = UIToolbar()
     toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
     toolBar.isTranslucent = true
     toolBar.sizeToFit()
     let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.cancel, target: nil, action: #selector(self.cancelPicker))
     let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
     let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.donePicker))
     toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
     toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
     textField1.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
     textField2.inputAccessoryView = toolBar   
    }
  @objc func cancelPicker() {
     //cancel that particular pickerview
   }
    @objc func donePicker() {
      // get that particular value in textfield
    }
```

both the textfields and pickerviews are connected as IBOutlets.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect which textfield has been focused and store a reference to it(I stored its index) and when done or cancel button on your toolbar is tapped, you can change value for that specific textfield.

I changed your code as below.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var textFields : [UITextField]!
    @IBOutlet var pickerviews : [UIPickerView]!
    
    
    let array = ["one" , "two" , "three"]
    
    var selectedTextfieldIndex : Int?
    var selectedTitle : String?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        for pickerview in pickerviews
        {
            pickerview.delegate = self
            pickerview.dataSource = self
        }
        
        for textfield in textFields
        {
            textfield.delegate = self
        }
        
        
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.cancel, target: nil, action: #selector(self.cancelPicker))
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.donePicker))
        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textFields[0].inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        textFields[1].inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        
        
        textFields[0].inputView = pickerviews[0]
        textFields[1].inputView = pickerviews[1]
    }
    
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        
        for ( index , item) in textFields.enumerated()
        {
            if textField == item
            {
                selectedTextfieldIndex = index
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    @objc func cancelPicker() {
        
        guard let index = selectedTextfieldIndex else { return }

        textFields[index].text = nil
        selectedTextfieldIndex = nil
        textFields[index].endEditing(true)

    }
    
    @objc func donePicker() {
        
        guard let index = selectedTextfieldIndex else { return }
        
        textFields[index].text = selectedTitle
        selectedTextfieldIndex = nil
        textFields[index].endEditing(true)

    }
    
}



extension ViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate , UIPickerViewDataSource
{
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return array[row]
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        self.selectedTitle = array[row]
    }
}
```